# Issues with insertion function for binary min-heap priority queue

Tags: c++, priority-queue, min-heap

I'm currently struggling with an assignment involving the implementation of a priority queue using a binary min-heap. The user inserts values upon startup, and then has the options to insert more values, delete the minimum value, or print the priority queue. I have everything implemented, except that I can't seem to correctly implement my insertion function.

My code for the implementation file:

```
#include "PriorityQueue.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

PriorityQueue::PriorityQueue():arrSize(100), currentSize(0){
  arr = new int[arrSize];
  for(int i = 0; i <= arrSize; i++){
    arr[i] = 0;
  }
}

bool PriorityQueue::isEmpty(){
  if (currentSize == 0){
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}

void PriorityQueue::insert(int value){
  currentSize++;
  int index = currentSize;
  arr[index] = value;
  int parent=(index-1)/2;
  while(index !=0 && arr[parent]>arr[index]){
    int temp = arr[index];
    arr[index]=arr[parent];
    arr[parent] = temp;
    index=parent;
  }
}

int PriorityQueue::deleteMin(){
  int min = arr[1];
  arr[1] = arr[currentSize];
  currentSize--;
  percolateDown(1);
  return min;
}

void PriorityQueue::printQueue(){
  for (int i = 1; i < currentSize+1; i++){
    cout << arr[i] << " ";
  }
  cout << endl;
}

void PriorityQueue::percolateDown(int hole){
  int minIndex = hole;
  int left = (2*hole);
  int right = (2*hole)+1;

  if (left <= currentSize && arr[left] < arr[minIndex]){
    minIndex = left;
  }

  if (right <= currentSize && arr[right] < arr[minIndex]){
    minIndex = right;

  }

  if(minIndex != hole){
      int temp = arr[hole];
      arr[hole] = arr[minIndex];
      arr[minIndex] = temp;
    }
}
```

For example, if I insert `100 70 50 125 45 60 10`, it will return `50 45 10 125 70 60 100` instead of `10 50 45 125 100 70 60`. Occasionally, the queue will be correctly ordered. I notice that it almost always fails to put the minimum value in the correct place.

**Edit:** Changing the for loop statement in printQueue() to start at 0 instead of 1 doesn't change the output apart from adding an arbitrary 0. I've changed `i <= currentSize` to `i < currentSize+1`. Currently debugging.

Comment: *I have everything implemented, except that I can't seem to correctly implement my insertion function.* -- [What is a debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i <= currentSize; i++)` -- In C++, arrays and indexing start at 0, not 1.  Writing code that tries to fake C++ into starting at 1 has a very good chance of being off-by-one somewhere, either at the left end (accessing element 0 when you didn't mean to do this), or on the right end (accessing an element out-of-bounds).

Comment: Extending the above comment, any time you see a `<=` in a loop exit condition you should stop and read the loop more closely. You're probably looking at a bug.

Comment: You have to decide whether you want the first item in your queue to be at `arr[0]` or at `arr[1]`. In your `insert` method you have `int parent=(index-1)/2;`, which is the calculation if you have a 0-based queue. But in your `deletMin` you treat it as though the root is at `arr[1]`. Either will work, but you have to pick one or the other.